# Difference between code inside useEffect with no dependencies and outside of it?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble wrapping my head around code that is inside a useEffect without dependencies vs. code that is simply outside useEffect.

For e.g, a simplistic example:

```
const func1 = () => {

  console.log("Apple") 

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Banana") 
  })

  return (//...JSX)
}
```

I believe BOTH `Apple` and `Banana` would be called at re-renders, so why use useEffect at all?

The standard answer I've heard is that `Apple` will be called at every re-render but `Banana` will be called only when a state/prop changes.

But a state / prop changing should almost always cause a re-render anyway so is there really a benefit of having that inside useEffect?

Comment: functions inside useEffect() runs after the component renders and not during component initialization. Functions inside useEffect will not be called again if the dependencies stays the same

Comment: As @Dupocas said, theres no functional difference here. The class based equivalent would be the effect acting as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, and the log outside of the effect being inside your `render` function. Both get called each render just at slightly different times.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I had the same exact same doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are right! Both codes run on each render, but the difference is **when**.

Consider the following

```
const Component = () =>{
    const ref = useRef(null)

    console.log(ref.current) // null
 
    useEffect(() => console.log(ref.current) /*div*/)

    return <div ref={ref} />
}
```

`useEffect` runs after the component is mounted. So for your example `useEffect` is useless but if you need to access a value which is only available after the component is mounted (measure the DOM for example) effects are usually the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. A follow-up question: In your example, you need something from the DOM so need to have the component mounted first. That makes sense. But what if all you need is to process the props received or process state variables to determine what to render. In that case is it better to have this code in initialization vs. useEffect?

Comment: Just do it directly inside your component's body

Comment: So I guess stuff like whether or not a user should be redirected to another URL should be done outside `useEffect` method right ?

Comment: Yes, any imperative code should go inside `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, I don't think there is a benefit in having that in the **useEffect** hook. But the 2 lines of code are executed at different times. The one outside **useEffect** is not hindered by the component life cycle - I think it is called as the component is being rendered. The one inside the **useEffect** hook however is called when the component has been mounted or updated as stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in the react docs.